# Concern about recent closures of community wiki questions

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Taking a look at the [highest-voted community wiki questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=wiki%3a1%20is%3aquestion), it appears lot of them have been recently closed, which is concerning to me, as these are (IMO) some of the most useful questions on the site, and certainly some of the most trafficked.

Some examples:

- [What Makes a Map Beautiful?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/what-makes-a-map-beautiful)
- [How do various JavaScript mapping libraries compare?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/how-do-various-javascript-mapping-libraries-compare)
- [What free programs should every GIS user have installed?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/what-free-programs-should-every-gis-user-have-installed)
- [What books, journals, and electronic resources are most valuable for expanding knowledge of GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202/what-books-journals-and-electronic-resources-are-most-valuable-for-expanding-k)
- [Where to find QGIS tutorials and web resources?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3651/where-to-find-qgis-tutorials-and-web-resources)
- [What are some resources for learning ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53816/what-are-some-resources-for-learning-arcpy)
- [Great GIS, maps & cartography quotes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/927/great-gis-maps-cartography-quotes)
- [What software do you use as complementary to your GIS desktop/server?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2712/what-software-do-you-use-as-complementary-to-your-gis-desktop-server)
- [GIS developer blogs ... recommendations?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32293/gis-developer-blogs-recommendations)
- [What are useful websites for scouting GIS related jobs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6645/what-are-useful-websites-for-scouting-gis-related-jobs)

Does anyone else share this concern?

I for one do not see a benefit to closing all of these, except perhaps for the reduction of low-quality posts from new users, which is what [protected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) questions are for.

Comment: Looks like this was discussed at least in part here: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/should-older-questions-not-meeting-current-standards-be-closed-or-locked -- I'm not convinced that a consensus was formed, however.

Comment: Using the first example, beautiful maps as an example - based on the "rules and guidelines", does it fit GIS.SE? Probably not. But I think it's a great question and I find myself once or twice a year looking at the new answers because it's an interesting question and has interesting answers. I like all the above examples you cited and don't see any harm to the community as a whole having them available for answers, edits or comments. Just my opinion that they're useful, despite whatever rules and guidelines SE has.

Comment: I think the activity is a result of my question, where I've already expressed my opinions. Yours seems to be garnering more attention. Beyond satisfying the criteria PolyGeo mentions, I see no point in closing. A successful closure can just be reopened again by numerous people, and which way either vote goes seems to depend on who sees the review queue first (so it's pretty much arbitrary or based on opinions of who visits most frequently). I see little point in 'protection' - it stops people from making it their first answer, but only takes one upvoted answer (10 rep) to gain the privilege.

Comment: I too think that many of those questions are valuable (as I stated in my original question). My biggest problem, and part of why I want no part of moderation (beyond voting, so my opinion is balanced with that of others) is that I can't reconcile the constant closing of new questions that are similar to these as too broad/opinion based/shopping list while allowing them to remain open and continuing to attract new answers (many of which often duplicate previous answers). Arbitrary enforcement in site management/policy is/can be a huge problem and drive a number of people away.

Comment: To your point, that's what I like about SE...to me the voting mechanism reduces the need for moderation. Of course there will always be instances moderation is required (abuse for example), but typical problems in a traditional forum, like duplication for example, can be handled by the collective with enough votes. If 5 people think something should be closed, odds are 1 of them will ask for more details and encourage the questioner to refine their query, hopefully reducing the sting a new use may feel having their 1st question closed.