# Who can edit Wiki Answer locked posts?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, community-wiki, locked-questions

While searching for comparisons between Javascript Mapping frameworks, I keep being linked back to this question:
[How do various JavaScript mapping libraries compare?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/how-do-various-javascript-mapping-libraries-compare)

Which, before it was locked, had a lot of great answers.  But the question and answers seem to have gone stale.  Probably due to it being locked.

This message is presented, but the edit links are disabled:

> This question's answers are a collaborative effort: if you see
>   something that can be improved, just edit the answer to improve it! No
>   additional answers can be added here

Who are the edit links enabled for? Moderators?  Do moderators have sufficient breadth of knowledge to maintain the content of this Question and its answers?

There seems to be an argument for removal of locked questions:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289381/question-locks-considered-harmful

Although I like the [How do various JavaScript mapping libraries compare?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/how-do-various-javascript-mapping-libraries-compare) question and if it was more current, it would be useful to me.

But I think having it locked has caused its quality to degrade over time.  And having to go through a moderator just to update content probably turns folks away.  Not to mention that a locked community wiki Q&A seems counter productive.

And what is the criteria for a locked community wiki?  It seems to me that if you can't edit a question or its answers, it doesn't qualify as a Wiki.

Although it is in line with this answer: ([Concern about recent closures of community wiki questions](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4014/concern-about-recent-closures-of-community-wiki-questions)) states that:

> Community Wiki status does not impact the case for Historical Locking,
>   Closing or Deleting of questions.

---

After [@PolyGeo](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/users/115/polygeo)'s response I checked, and although I have 9K+ in rep, I still can't edit the top post. At least not from the link:

[image]

---

I am able to edit if I type the following in the address window:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/8048/edit

It's not exactly intuitive and probably not conducive for healthy maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question has a Wiki Answer lock so its answers should be editable by anybody with a reputation of 100 or more.

For more information on why I think it is sensibly locked see [my answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4381/115) to [Are software recommendations good candidates for being wiki locked?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4380/115)

There is no need for you to involve a moderator to edit any of the answers to a Wiki Answer-locked question but you are correct that only a moderator can edit the question.

The above represents my understanding of a Meta SE Q&A: [Reputation needed to edit Q&As with Wiki Answer lock?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296710/reputation-needed-to-edit-qas-with-wiki-answer-lock)

If you are not able to simply visit one of that questions answers and click **edit** to start editing it, then I think you should post that at [Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) because it would seem to be a bug.